# Citing articles in R package using roxygen2 and BibTeX?

Tags: r, documentation, bibtex, roxygen2, citations

I'm using roxygen2 as a tool for documenting my R package, and I found that there is a @references tag in roxygen2, but that seems to only accept free form text. I found some presentation about roxygen which has tags @bibliograph and @cite, but am I correct that there is no such thing in roxygen2?

Should I then somehow take the references out of the bibtex-file and write them manually with appropriate formatting directly after the @references tag or is there some more clever way of doing this? I have about seven different articles I need to cite, over multiple functions/rd-files.

Comment: Meanwhile if you don't want to enter these manually, you might consider looking at the [bibtex package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bibtex/index.html) on cran.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Seems that there is a brand new pull request contributing this feature:
https://github.com/klutometis/roxygen/pull/90

So hopefully we'll soon have this functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Until the functionality mentioned by cbeleites is integrated with roxygen2 (and five years on it has not been), the Rdpack package provides the best way of using Bibtex in R.

For details, see [Citing articles using roxygen2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28190868/citing-articles-using-roxygen2/47473974#47473974).