# Citing articles using roxygen2

Tags: r

As in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10207564/1414455), I would like to include citations to articles in function documentation. I use `roxygen2` for all documentation, and it appears that there was a [pull request](https://github.com/klutometis/roxygen/pull/90) to `roxygen2` with the necessary functionality, but Hadley turned it down since `roxygen2` was in maintenance mode. Have things changed since then? Is there another way to cite/ include article references stored in BibTeX format?

Comment: Try to put a "CITATION" file under inst folder of your package? For example, https://github.com/cran/GMD/blob/master/inst/CITATION

Comment: @xb No, that is the citation for the package, not to cite external articles.

Comment: Then try to include a .bib file in your .Rnw if you use such type of vignette? For example,  `\bibliographystyle{plain} \bibliography{vignette.bib}`

Comment: @xb Thanks, but again, that is a different use case. I want to be able to use something like the proposed `@cite` tag from the pull request to cite articles as I write inline `roxygen2` function documentation. I am aware that `RMarkdown` allows external bibliographies.

Answer (score 8):

The [Rdpack package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rdpack/vignettes/Inserting_bibtex_references.pdf) promises to deliver the functionality that you requested.

To get set up, you also need to add the line `RdMacros: Rdpack` to your package's `DESCRIPTION` file (note the capital M), and add `Rdpack` to the `Imports:` field.

Then you can save your bibtex library in to `inst/REFERENCES.bib`, and cite them in your documentation with:

```
#' @references{
#'   \insertRef{bibtexKey}{YourPackageName}
#' }
#'
#' # The below line ought to be included in at least one of your documentation
#' # sections, so that roxygen2 adds Rdpack to your NAMESPACE file.
#'
#' @importFrom Rdpack reprompt
```

I initially encountered some errors when first using the package; re-starting R seemed to do the trick.

Warnings about `unknown macro '\insertRef'` will be encountered if building documentation with `devtools::document()`, as devtools does not read the 'RdMacros' line of the DESCRIPTION file; they can be safely ignored. The references may not be rendered correctly by devtools, but will be when the package is finally built; to view them in their proper formatting in the interim you can run `R CMD Rd2pdf` from a separate command window.

Answer (score 6):

Nicely summarized by ms609. I would add that the releases of [Rdpack](https://cran.r-project.org/package=Rdpack) in 2018 provided also macros for citation and the ability to produce the bibliography with a single command `insertAllCited{}`. Vignette [Inserting_bibtex_references](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rdpack/vignettes/Inserting_bibtex_references.pdf), linked also by ms609, provides up-to-date information.

`Rdpack::viewRd()` can be used to view the rendered citations without building the package, something like:

```
Rdpack::viewRd("./man/filename.Rd")  # text
Rdpack::viewRd("./man/filename.Rd", type = "html") # html
```

This may be particularly useful for `roxygen2` users since `roxygen2` processes the Rd files but doesn't render the references. Just don't forget to update the documentation using `devtools::document()` or another suitable command before invoking `Rdpack::viewRd()`.

Comment: Note that you cannot put four spaces or more before \insertAllCited{}!

Comment: Indeed, but only if you have activated markdown for your roxygen2 comments. Note that the example by @mc609 above can be used safely, the trouble occurs only if you have activated markdown and aligned `\insertRef` with the second e of @references.