# Use Roxygen2 template tags in references section

Tags: r, templates, r-package

I'm confident with the basics of [Using Roxygen2 Template tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15100129/using-roxygen2-template-tags), which work fine when replacing calls to `@param`, but am having problems using templates to add references to a reference section.

My template at `man-roxygen/refEstabrook1985.R` reads

```
#' \cite{Estabrook G.F., McMorris F.R., Meacham C.A. 1985. Comparison of undirected phylogenetic trees based on subtrees of four evolutionary units. Syst. Zool. 34:193--200.}
```

I've tried a few ways to link this to a references block.

#### No braces

```
#' @references
#' @template refEstabrook1985
```

gives the warning `Warning: @references [QuartetDistance.R#218]: requires a value` and doesn't render the references section.

#### Braces, no spaces

```
#' @references {
#' @template refEstabrook1985
#' }
```

gives the warnings
 `Warning: @references [QuartetDistance.R#218]: mismatched braces or quotes
Warning: @template [QuartetDistance.R#219]: mismatched braces or quotes` and doesn't render the references section in the .Rd file.

#### Braces and spaces

```
#' @references {
#'  @template refEstabrook1985
#' }
```

(note the additional space) gives no warnings, but doesn't expand the template, so the manual page reads "References:  @template refEstabrook1985"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've established that what I want to do is impossible. The [Roxygen manual](http://roxygen.org/roxygen2-manual.pdf) states that

> Templates must be composed of complete tags - because all roxygen tags are current block tags, they can not be used for inline insertions.

An alternative is to use Rdpack: see [Citing articles using roxygen2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28190868/citing-articles-using-roxygen2/47473974#47473974)